# Django expects wrong format when validating modelform datefield

Tags: django, django-forms, python-datetime, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a page where the user inputs some dates in the `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

In my settings file I have this:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y','%Y/%m/%d', '%Y-%m-%d',) 
USE_TZ = True
USE_L10N = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Rome
```

I use the [django bootstrap4 datetime picker plus](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/)

The field renders as such: (i apologize about the screenshot, i couldnt copy the html without it being escaped and it looked extra-messy)

[image]

### The problem

The problem is that when i input dates in dd/mm/yyyy format, it uses the american format (mm/dd/yyyy) to validate them. So if i enter 27/12/2021 it will try to save [day 12, month 27, year 2021] and fail the validation. Preventing the formset from being saved.

What i don't understand is where in hell does django get the idea that it should use the american format to validate dates when I have set three separate `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` and none of them are in the american format?

Here an image showing that on the page the date is collected in the right format
[image]

And the response : `[{'start_date': ['Enter a valid date.'], 'end_date': ['Enter a valid date.']}]`

### Forms

this is where i am now:

```
class EducationForm(forms.ModelForm):

# def clean_start_date(self):
#     print(self.cleaned_data['start_date'])
#     return datetime.strptime((self.cleaned_data['start_date']), '%Y-%m-%d')
# def clean_end_date(self):
#     return datetime.strptime((self.cleaned_data['end_date']),  '%Y-%m-%d')

    class Meta:
        model = Education
        fields = ['start_date', 'end_date', 'institution', 'title']
        # localized_fields = ('start_date', 'end_date',)
        widgets = {
            'start_date': DatePickerInput(attrs={
                'data-provide' : 'datepicker',
                'class' : 'form-control my-date-picker',
                # 'data-date-format' : "DD/MM/YYYY"
            },
            options={
                "format": "DD/MM/YYYY",
            }),
            'end_date': DatePickerInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Ongoing',
                'data-provide' : 'datepicker',    
                'class' : 'form-control my-date-picker',           
                # 'data-date-format' : "DD/MM/YYYY"
            },
            options={
                "format": "DD/MM/YYYY",
            }),
```

### Template

In the template there's nothing particular going on. I just render the datetime fields as {{ field }}.

Comment: I see that you have a commented out `localized_fields` line. Do you have `USE_L10N` set to true in your settings? That changes the date format behavior if so.

Comment: I did not have it in my settings. I have added it and tested it after you suggested it. Alas, it did not work.

Comment: This might be daft, but perhaps you have another line in your settings for `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`, hence what you set isn't actually used?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I do this type of mistakes all the time but this is not one of those times.

Comment: I also realized in the settings i had `TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Rome` and `USE_TZ = True`. Do you think they're affecting this somehow?

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong, then. Have you been able to validate what the form data looks like when received by the view? Or confirm the `input_formats` attribute of the `DateField`s? I'd usually try to do that pdb and running the server via the Django process directly, if my environment is simple enough for that to work - failing that additional logging ought to do it, say with an extra block in your view. The code for date conversion is pretty simple and readable: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/fields.py#L372

Comment: Oh, btw, I wouldn't have `USE_L10N` on unless you actually need it - that was a question aimed at a theory about why your formats setting wasn't working as expected, not a recommendation. If you do need it, you'd probably want to work out the current locale's date format and make sure you set your datepicker widget to match.

Comment: So you are saying that in theory i could intercept the POST data in the view and rearrange the date string before it gets converted into a datetime object?

Comment: In theory, but you shouldn't need to rearrange the string - just validate that it's formatted as you expect. Debugging, not bug-fixing - the problem is that the input (for as yet unknown reasons) doesn't match the formats the date field objects are expecting, and it's better to figure out why and fix that directly, making the sending format from the form agree with the parsing format(s) expected by the field objects.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on how you'd implement a solution? Im a bit out of my depth here.. The way i see it the problem is not with the input but rather with the datefield's format expectations..

Comment: If i yield to the caprices of the timefield i will have dates stored in an unfamiliar way and i will have to convert them back and forth for all eternity

Comment: There's nothing wrong with datefields conceptually. You have a bug somewhere - either your form is not providing the format you expect, or the datefields have been created with an incorrect set of `input_format` values. Step one is to figure out which of those is the case, so in your view logging things like `request.POST['start_date']` and `form.fields['start_date'].input_formats` will let you pin down where the problem lies. You can't fix it until you know precisely what the problem is.

Comment: Im logging the input formats and there is definitely something fishy going on here. I will collect some more complete logs and then i will expand the question

Comment: I get 3 different input formats for the same field 0_0  
web_1          | input format :::: %Y-%m-%d

web_1          | input format :::: %m/%d/%Y

web_1          | input format :::: %m/%d/%y

Comment: Well, it's normal for `input_formats` to be a sequence so multiple values is expected, but you'd expect it to be the sequence given in your settings. Those look like the first few values of the default list (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) - I would double or triple check for typos in your settings field name and otherwise dig in to make sure your Django process is running successfully from that settings file. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#seeing-which-settings-you-ve-changed might help with that!

Comment: Thank you so much, after learning a bit about input_formats i now understand the issue. I never would have made it without your help. I didnt solve it yet but now at least i understand in which direction to dig. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the solution was adding `USE_L10N = False` to my settings file.
It appears that unless specified, django will disregard the contents of  `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`

Comment: thank you, I've been having the same problem and I couldn't find a solution